# UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler in windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8.1

I'm trying to make an application for windows 8.1, and as part of the application I'm trying to port libgit2sharp to a windows 8.1 class library (not the portable class library). I've managed to convert a lot of the minor issues, but a significant portion of the project uses `UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler` and `ICustomMarshaler` which does not seem to be supported for some reason. Is there a way to get this to work, or a way around using this?

Thank you.

EDIT: Here's the github url if you need to check it out: https://github.com/mirhagk/windows8git

Comment: What's the error you get in the Errors window?

Comment: `'System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType' does not contain a definition for 'CustomMarshaler'` and 
`The type or namespace name 'ICustomMarshaler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` are the errors. I've modified my question to include the github url if you need to look at the project file or anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's just no happy answer to give here.  The System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType enumeration from the System.Runtime.InteropServices reference assembly **explicitly** omits the CustomMarshaler enum.  And of course the ICustomMarshaler interface is missing as well, just like the compiler told you.

You could fake the UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler value (44) but there is no way that you can fake the interface, a replacement version you'd write will have the wrong type identity.

This omission was intentional.

Do beware that this isn't likely to be your only obstacle.  If you port native code then you have to observe the white-list of approved winapi functions.  It is a [short list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn424765.aspx).  When you use the SDK headers then they'll keep you out of trouble.  But be sure to never tinker with the WINAPI_FAMILY macro to solve a compile error, that doesn't solve anything.  Just copying a DLL never works either.  The Store verification procedure will reject your app if you do.

Comment: Okay, looks like I won't be using any of the git libraries for C# then, libgit2sharp is pretty closely tied to the native program, and they others use quite a few functions which aren't supported on windows 8. I'll have to see if I can pull a subset of functionality out of one of them.

Comment: ps I've marked this as the correct answer, but I will wait a little bit before awarding the bounty.